# Check if the type of a variable is dict[str, Any] in Python

Tags: python, types, typeerror

I want to check if the type of a variable is: dict[str, Any]. (in python)

What I have tried (unsuccessfully) is this:

```
myvar = {
 'att1' : 'some value',
 'att2' : 1
}


if not isinstance(myvar, dict[str, Any]):
  raise Exception('Input has the wrong type')
```

I get the following error message:

> TypeError: isinstance() argument 2 cannot be a parameterized generic

How should I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: dont use `input` as a var name. It is a bad practice. It is a built-in function

Comment: A type checker like `mypy` can check that for you. But not in runtime.

Comment: in my actual code, I didn't use input, I thought it would make the question easier to understand, I changed it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the below - make sure you have a dict and the keys of the dict are strings.

```
data1 = {
    'att1': 'some value',
    'att2': 1
}

data2 = {
    'att1': 'some value',
    13: 1
}


def check_if_dict_with_str_keys(data):
    return isinstance(data, dict) and all(isinstance(x, str) for x in data.keys())


print(check_if_dict_with_str_keys(data1))
print(check_if_dict_with_str_keys(data2))
```

output

```
True
False
```

Comment: Look at `mypy` if you want to check the code BEFORE you run it.

Comment: @balderman — You can remove the call to `data.keys()` and simply have `return isinstance(data, dict) and all(isinstance(x, str) for x in data)`. `iter(data)` returns an iterator over the dictionary's keys anyway, and is faster than iterating over the `KeysView` proxy that `data.keys()` returns.

Comment: It is possible to add this to the function signature to get it type safe
```TypeGuard[dict[str, Any]]:```

So the full function name would be:
```def check_if_dict_with_str_keys(data: Any) -> TypeGuard[dict[str, Any]]: ```

Answer (score 1):

`isinstance` doesn't work like type hinting does.

The correct code for that is:

```
if isinstance(input, dict):
```

But that doesn't do what I think you want: check if all keys in the dict are str and all values are Any. Basically, you want all keys to be str, so the code to achieve that would be something like:

```
if all(map(lambda k: isinstance(k, str), input.keys())):
```

or some such.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do here is not supported:

```
if not isinstance(input, dict[str, Any]):
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type):

> The builtin functions `isinstance()` and `issubclass()` do not accept `GenericAlias` types for their second argument:
>
> ```py
> >>> isinstance([1, 2], list[str])
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: isinstance() argument 2 cannot be a parameterized generic
> ```

Instead, you can only perform this:

```
if not isinstance(input, dict):
```

If you want to check the type of the elements of the `dict` container, what you can do is iterate over its items and then check their types (as done in the other answers).